# Create only one div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I create a div with jQuery. It works well but each time the user clicks the button it creates a new div. I want to create **only one** div with the unique id. How can I control that?

Here to test: http://jsfiddle.net/g4978v4h/

JQUERY:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'red').insertAfter("#button");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="button"></div>
```

Comment: Check the DOM for the ID and if it exists don't create a new element if it does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The div with id `red` should only be added once?
Then use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to attach the click handler

```
$("#button").one("click", function() {
    $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'red').insertAfter("#button");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $('#red').length == 0 && $('<div></div>')
        .attr('id', 'red')
        .insertAfter("#button");
```

You can try to check if div already exist

http://jsfiddle.net/g4978v4h/1/

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this

for instance you can declare a global variable and check for its count

```
var a = 1;
$("#button").click(function() {

    if(a == 1)
    {
    $('<div></div>')
        .attr('id', 'red')
        .insertAfter("#button");
        a = a+1;
    }
});
```

as shown in the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4978v4h/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the `#red` doesn't exist. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4978v4h/4/)

```
  $("#button").click(function() {
        if($('#red').length == 0 )  
        {
        $('<div></div>')
            .attr('id', 'red')
            .insertAfter("#button");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var divCreated = false;
$("#button").click(function() {
if (!divCreated) {
      var newDiv = $("<div id='red'></div>");
      $("body").append(newDiv);
      divCreated = true;
    }
});
```

```css
#button{
    width: 100px; height: 30px;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:4px;
    background-color:Gainsboro;
    cursor: pointer; 
  line-height:30px
}

#red{
    width:100px;height: 100px;
    background-color: #C00;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">Click</div>
```